# RegEx for phone number with no consecutive duplicate numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

My current RegEx for phone number validation is `^\d{8,}$` which validates minimum length is 8 and does not allow special characters or letters and my question is what's the RegEx which does not allow 9-15 consecutive duplicate numbers plus the current condition (minimum length is 8 and no special characters or letters allowed).

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this regex will do it:

```js
/^(?!.*(\d)\1{8})\d{8,}$/
```

Here is a commented version (in C# syntax):

```cs
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"
    # Match digits sequence  with no same digit 9 times in a row.
    ^                # Anchor to start of string
    (?!.*(\d)\1{8})  # Assert no digit repeats 9 times.
    \d{8,}           # Match eight or more digits.
    $                # Anchor to end of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: I am looking for a regex to validate if string does not contain same number consecutively 7-10 times. The allowed inputs are 0-9. I tried using the above regex /^(?!.*(\d)\1{8})\d{8,}$/ but it did not help. Please help.

Comment: Could you please help with above query.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the regex in a better way

NODE                     EXPLANATION

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
   (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
     (                        group and capture to \1:
      \d                       digits (0-9)
     )                        end of \1
    \1{8}                    what was matched by capture \1 (8 times)
   )                        end of look-ahead
  \d{8,}                   digits (0-9) (at least 8 times (matching
                       the most amount possible))
 $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                       string
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding the comments of my expression to better describe the goings-on inside the lookahead. Its good to see another "attention-to-details" regexpert around here! +1

Comment: @Ridgerunner: I aint a regexpert....But loving them....
[http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl] will help in understanding the intricacies of a regex...

Answer (score 0):

So `11111111` (8 `1`s) is ok, but `111111111` (9 `1`s) isn't?

A regex isn't *always* the right answer.  I'd keep the existing `^\d{8,}$` regex and then check for repeated digits separately.  Since you're only (for now?) forbidding 10 distinct numbers, you could just set up a hash of forbidden numbers and check against it:

```
my %forbidden = map { $_ x 9 => 1 } 0..9;

...

if ($num =~ /^\d{8,}$/ and not $forbidden{$num}) {
    # accept
}
else {
    # reject
}
```